# How capture "ANALYZE VERBOSE tablename" output into logfile

Tags: postgresql, shell

I would like to capture output of "ANALYZE VERBOSE TableName" into output file when executed from shell script.

Want to capture this:

> INFO:  analyzing "tablename" INFO:  "tablename": scanned 1 of 1 pages,
>   containing 7 live rows and 2 dead rows; 7 rows in sample, 7 estimated
>   total rows

Using this command

```
psql -h $DB_HOST_NAME -U $DB_USER $DB_NAME -f query.txt --echo-errors --echo-queries >> output.log
```

But its only capturing text "ANALYZE" not capturing entire text.

Please suggest how to print entire text into output file.

Comment: replace and try `--echo-queries >> output.log` with `--echo-queries 2>&1 >> output.log`

Comment: Its still not capturing details :( @PS.

Comment: I think it should be --echo-queries >> outfile 2>&1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are trying to capture is directed through stderr, so you need to capture/redirect that output at the shell level. This can be tempermental based on your versions of your OS / Shell. On OSX with 3.2.57, you would need to use:

`psql -h $DB_HOST_NAME -U $DB_USER $DB_NAME -f query.txt --echo-queries >> output.log 2>&1 ;`

If that doesn't work, try looking up the specifics for whatever combination of OS/shell you are using.